# Catch error thrown inside $.getJSON().done()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, try-catch, getjson

I'm accessing and doing some stuff with a JSON file. If the ajax call fails the error can be caught by `.fail()`, but when I throw an error inside `.done()` it doesn't get caught.

```
function myFunc() {
    $.getJSON('data.json')
    .done(db => {
        /* do stuff with JSON */
        if (condition) {
            throw Error(message);
        }
    })
    .fail(error => {
        throw Error("getJSON request failed.\n" + error);
    })
}

try {
    myFunc();
} catch (e) {
    /* handle error */
}
```

I understand this is because the function is asynchronous. How can I make sure this error is caught, and that myFunch() finishes executing before ending the try-catch block?

Comment: Don't use `done` and `fail`. Always use `then` or `catch`.

Comment: And no, `try/catch` will never handle asynchronous exceptions, unless you are using `async/await`.

Comment: How would I convert this to try/catch with async/await?